# storing results of the power spectrum density command in a matrix - matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, signal-processing

I need a bit of help with some matlab code regarding for loops and power spectral densities.

I'm analysing a signal and need to be able to measure the average power in each each 30 second segment. I have split the signal with the function 'buffer'so that 30 seconds worth of data lie in each column of the matrix `segment_mat` but I want to be able to store the results of the power spectral density in a matrix using a for loop to loop through the data and to also store the average power of each segment in a vector `avpow`. Any thoughts where i might be going wrong?

```
for j=1:120
    Hs=spectrum.periodogram({'Hamming'});
    Power=psd(Hs,segment_mat(:,j)',fs',fs);
    avpow=mean(Power(j))';
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that you are overwriting the results in every iteration of the `for` loop.

Just modify your code so:

```
Power(j) = ...
avpow(j) = ...
```

and you will be storing the results of your calculations. Consider pre-allocating if speed is an issue.